# AFNetworking/Blocks code executed on main thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I have AFNetworking implemented in my app and it's using Blocks (as far as I know) to call the finish functions.
I have this code:

```
[MANAGER POST:GET_HISTORY_URL parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     //CODE FOR MAIN THREAD
 }];
```

Is the "CODE FOR MAIN THREAD" code excuted on the main thread or do I have to do a perform selector on main thread?
Also the same question for any types of blocks for example an animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:QUESTION_TIME_ON_SCREEN animations:^{
    questionViewBottomBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, questionViewBackground.frame.size.height - questionViewBottomBarFrame.size.height, 0, questionViewBottomBarFrame.size.height);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //CODE FOR MAIN THREAD
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes and yes, it is just performed on main thread, no need for another perform.